# Does QueryAsync calls OpenAsync with Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper, sqlconnection, asp.net-core-3.0

I have come upon a bit of code that looks like this (it is based of Dapper tutorial):

```
await using var con = new SqlConnection("some connection");
if (CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) await con.OpenAsync(CancellationToken);
return await con.QueryAsync(query, parameters);
```

How I am understanding this is if Cancellation token was set then it will open an async connection with that token. However if it is not set then it will not try to open a connection and instead it will just call the query statement.

What I'm trying to understand is if you don't call `con.OpenAsync` will `con.QueryAsync` call it? Essentially do I need to explicitly call it if there is no cancellation token?

Comment: Dapper is open source, you could take a look at the code (if the documentation doesn't already specify).

Comment: From my recollection of the source code it opens the connection if it is not already open

Comment: indeed: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs#L406-L418

Comment: unrelated, but if this Dapper tutorial is publicly available, I'd love to eyeball it (frankly, I'm amazed that *not once* has anyone asked me to eyeball such a tutorial for correctness, but many such exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm trying to understand is if you don't call `con.OpenAsync` will `con.QueryAsync` call it?

[yes](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs#L406-L418)

> Essentially do I need to explicitly call it if there is no cancellation token?

no; you don't need to call it *with or without* a cancellation token

However! if you are going to perform multiple **related** operations - perhaps involving a temporary table or transaction - then you will need to do your own connection state management, i.e. you will need to call `Open[Async]` yourself (and `Close`, if you aren't disposing it immediately).